# How to extract paragraphs containing an expression using Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, full-text-search, paragraph

For example if this were the text:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sit amet tellus sit amet libero facilisis malesuada. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec eget auctor odio. Sed quam diam, varius in mollis eu, mollis vel felis. Vestibulum vitae porta enim.

Proin nisi ante, imperdiet **dignissim** ultricies eget, tristique eget massa. Vestibulum at condimentum nisi. Phasellus venenatis, ipsum id facilisis euismod, lorem risus hendrerit elit, sit amet porttitor justo sem laoreet massa. Sed id molestie dui, sit amet interdum neque.

I would like the regex String to match the whole (Proin...neque.) paragraph, given the wordToSearch **dignissim**.

At the moment I have been able to set up a regex String to extract single sentences (string that lies between dots) containing a given expression. This sets it up:

```
public static final String regexPhrase(String wordToSearch) {
        String regexPhraseString = "(((?<=\\.)((.(?![^p]\\.))+?))*?(\\b" + wordToSearch
                + "\\b{1,})(.*?)(p\\. .*?)*?(\\.))";
        return regexPhraseString;
    }
```

This works fine for my purpose, as it respects APA cites of the form (Surename, Year, p. X).

However, when trying to achieve the same idea with whole paragraphs instead of sentences, I can't find the way around it. My initial idea was to define a paragraph as the string between (dot+line break)...(dot+line break).
I have written an analogous code for this replacing `\\.` by `\\.\n` and erasing the `[p^]`, but does not seem to work:

```
public static final String regexParagraph(String wordToSearch) {
        String regexParagraphString = "(((?<=\\.\n)((.(?!\\.\n))+?))*?(\\b" + wordToSearch
        + "\\b{1,})(.*?)(\\.\n))";
        return regexParagraphString;
    }
```

Actually it has worked on simple texts but returns undesired outputs in more complex (long and rich) texts.

I would really appreciate some help with these regular expressions!

PD: I have the Pattern and Matcher all sorted out, it is just the regex String that is giving me trouble.

Comment: `\b{1,}` won't compile. Can't quantify a word boundary. https://regex101.com/r/4uKwaC/1

Comment: Is a p, dot, space, anything - intended with this `(p\. .*?)*?` ? If so, its better written as `(p\. .+?)*?`

Comment: @sln the `(p\\. .*?)*?`is intended for the the sentence to support cites having the page number: (García, 2005, p. 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use double line breaks as delimiters. As well as beginning of string, end of string.
Capture group 1 contains trimmed paragraph.

```
(?s-m)(?:^|(?:\R\s*\R))\s*((?:(?!\R\s*\R|\s*$).)*?dignissim(?:(?!\R\s*\R|\s*$).)*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/TZGmK4/1

```
 (?s-m)
 (?:
    ^ 
  | (?: \R \s* \R )
 )
 \s* 
 (                             # (1 start)
    (?:
       (?! \R \s* \R | \s* $ )
       . 
    )*?
    dignissim
    (?:
       (?! \R \s* \R | \s* $ )
       . 
    )*
 )                             # (1 end)
```